# Transform deforms a simple cylinder

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms

The cylinder is deformed when I try the transform node in Geometry Nodes as the attached picture (the current selected object).[image]. It rotates correctly (from vertical to horizontal, 90 degrees), but the length in z does not follow the rotation and the cross-section changes from circular to oval. Changing Y-rotation to 0 degree can let it return to normal vertical cylinder. Do I miss something? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to apply all transforms. you could also delete the group input and then re-add the cylinder within geonodes.

Comment: Thank you, Isaac! Can you show a simple picture how to do it? I am a novice to Blender. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now I understand "apply all transforms": ctrl+A, then in the Apply popup menu, click Scale. Thanks!